# Is there a way to forward a touchevent from a UIBarButtonItem with a customView?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, touch-event

I'm trying to use a customView as rightBarButtonItem using the `UIBarButtonItem(customView: UIView)` initializer. My customView is basically a stackView with two objects: an imageView and a label. I added a tapgesturerecognizer to the whole view. Using this view outside of the UIBarButtonItem (like a toast or similar) is not a problem. It seems that the event is intercepted by the button and not forwarded to it's customView.

Adding tapgesturerecognizer to customView (e.g. cloudView)

```swift
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewTapped))
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Adding the view to the NavigationBar:

```swift
let frame = navigationController!.navigationBar.frame
cloudView = UploadStatusView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width * 0.6, height: frame.height))
cloudView.changeLayoutToBeInsideNavigationBar()
cloudView.delegate = self

let cloudViewButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: cloudView)

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = cloudViewButton
```

I expect the event to be relayed, but that's not the case. Instead, nothing happens.

Comment: Pascal did set `customView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`?

Comment: @Lucho i tried it, but without success :(